# TabBarController inside a TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, tabbar

I am new in **IOS/objective-c/xcode** please be indulgent. My problem is that i don't know how to set a **tabbar inside a tabbar**.

- Firstable : I success to create a UITabBarController and his view :

[image: screenshot 1]

- Secondable: I also success to create a **UITabBarController** and position my tabbar of my second in the top. The picture is the result of when i click from my first tabbarcontroller.
- **The problem** is that my frist tabbar disappear from the screen. How can i have both ?
  any answer will be appreciated

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: for the second tabbar you could use uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: how (UITableController with uisegmentedcontrol or UIViewController with uisegmentedcontrol)  can you show a few exemple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's much better to use a segmentedControl instead of a second TabBar,

you can do something like:

[image]

is obviously just an example, and you can customize how you want the `segmentedControl`, how to remove the borders, change the color etc.

but in this way is better, and is much more manageable as implementation

i have added this `segmentedControl` from storyboard, but you can also do it programmatically

Comment: thanks, i use segmented control with NSArray of 5 UIView that i allocated dynamically and i can switch page with segmented control like in UITabbarController thanks again .